# Does customised setup from Live run transfer over at install?

Tags: usb-installation

I would like to pre-configure Ubuntu (MATE 18.04) on evenings and weekends while keeping my current Windows install until I am ready to make the switch. My setup includes installing software, browser plugins, etc. I'm saving the state using Virtual Box.

Will that setup transfer over when I finally click Install from the live run? If not, is there a relatively easy path to getting this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your setup a bit more detailed? I don't understand how you are running and saving the live session. Did you mount the ISO as virtual disk in a virtual machine?

Comment: Thank you, Danzel. As you guessed, I am indeed mounting the ISO as a virtual disk. Doing all that under Oracle's VM VirtualBox.

I have an SSD drive with default partitioning I do not understand (Lenovo's Yoga notebook) and am hesitant to create a new partition to simply install along side of Windows.